# C++: Pass interface as parameter like in Java

Tags: java, c++, c++11, lambda, interface

I want to do some stuff in C++ that i can do in Java. Here is my Java code:

```java
interface Worker
{
    public void work();
}

class Employer
{
    public void askForWork(Worker worker)
    {
        worker.work();
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employer employer = new Employer();
        employer.askForWork(new Worker()
        {
            @Override
            public void work()
            {
                System.out.println("I'm working!");
            }
        });
        employer.askForWork(new Worker()
        {
            @Override
            public void work()
            {
                System.out.println("I'm working too!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And I want to do it in C++. It is very important for me to be able to implement interface inside function call. Is it possible?

Comment: Show the code you've written so far.

Comment: Lookup abstract base class and virtual methods.

Comment: Show the C++ code you've written.

Comment: I'm written Object class(http://pastebin.com/XgVYbbny) and calling it as follows: http://pastebin.com/yJLVsT8E
But with this approach I can't serve any variables inside lambdas.

Comment: Also I written this: Updater class(http://pastebin.com/vrUAcpLM) and usage of it(http://pastebin.com/sxg7M882). But as you can see, I can't implement derived class inside function call :(

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use std::function.

```
class Worker {
 public:
  explicit Worker(std::function<void()> task)
      : task_(task) {}

  void Work() {
    task_();
  }

 private:
  std::function<void()> task_;
};

class Employer {
  ...

  void AskForWork(std::unique_ptr<Worker> worker) {
    worker->Work();
  }
};

int main(...) {
  Employer employer;
  employer.AskForWork(new Worker(
    []() {
      std::cout << "I'm working!" << std::endl;
    }
  ));
}
```

Comment: Yes, i did this way already, but how can I serve variables that do not changes inside this function?